# Vertical alignment of text on multiple lines

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, itemize

I use

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item \makebox[2.5cm][l]{some text} some very long text. some very long text. some very long text. some very long text.
\end{itemize}
```

to produce

[image]

The problem is that I want the second line of the item to be aligned with the second part of the item. So "some text" acts somehow like the item bullet. So I kind of want `\makebox{}` to also work in 'the vertical direction', such that no text is placed below this.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "I want the second line of the item to be aligned with the second part of the item". By "second part", do you mean the material after the boxed material?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are serveral solutions for such a thing, here are two. First using `labeling` environment of [`scrextend`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrextend) or any [KOMA-Script class](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script), second using a environment derived from `description` using [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem):

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}% you are using a sans serif font

% use package scrextend to have the labeling environment of KOMA-Script
\usepackage{scrextend}
\setkomafont{labelinglabel}{$\triangleright$\enskip}% ugly hack to have a
                                % triangle before the item

% use package enumitem to have an extended description environment
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand*{\descriptionlabelwith}[2]{\hspace\labelsep
  \normalfont#1\enskip #2}
\newlist{itemdesc}{description}{1}% currently only one level is definded
\setlist*[itemdesc,1]{font=\normalfont,format=\descriptionlabelwith{$\triangleright$},leftmargin=27mm,labelwidth=*}

\begin{document}
\begin{labeling}{\hspace{2.5cm}}
\item[some text] some very long text. some very long text. some very long text. some very long text.
\end{labeling}

\begin{itemdesc}
\item[some text] some very long text. some very long text. some very long text. some very long text.
\end{itemdesc}

\end{document}
```

[image: solution using labeling or enumitem]

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, but the triangle was already made by the `\begin{itemize}` environment. So I just need to create `some text [spaces] some very long text`, in which "some text" works as a label as in a description

Comment: @Jamgreen: And why not making a special list for this?